# EditText Character Countdown Issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, counter

I have constructed a counter label TextView that counts down the number of characters left in an EditText. I am allowing 196 characters inside the EditText. When the EditText character count reaches zero, I change the counter label's text color to red, and disable the EditText, so the user cannot enter more characters.

My problem arises when I attempt to delete the last character that was entered in order to enable user input. What I am trying to do is delete the last character so that the logic that disable's the EditText is no longer true, the EditText becomes enabled, the counter label's text color changes back to white, and the count is updated. However, the code I have written does not work, and the EditText remains disabled. I am using an addTextChangedListener to disable and an onTouchListener to try and re-enable.

I have managed to make this work for iOS using the TOUCHESBEGAN method which captures the user's touch, enables the UITextView, deletes the last character using the DELETEBACKWARD function, and updates the count. Can someone study my code and point me in the right direction for Android?

```
public class MessageInputView extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_input_view);

    final ImageView continueButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
    final ImageView backButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backButton);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView counterLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counterLabel);
    final int characterMax = 196;

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = (MediaPlayer.create(MessageInputView.this, R.raw.droplet_sound));

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            counterLabel.setText(characterMax - editable.toString().length() + " characters remaining");


            if (editText.length() == characterMax){

                counterLabel.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                editText.setEnabled(false);


            }


        }
    });

    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                editText.setEnabled(true);

                String userText = editText.getText().toString();

                editText.setText(userText.substring(0, userText.length() - 1));

                counterLabel.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                counterLabel.setText(characterMax - editText.length() + " characters remaining");

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could define max length of Edittext in XML.
Use the maxLength option.

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="196" >
    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I had initially started with setting maxLength in xml, but was using characterMax in place of editText in my IF statement within addTextChangedListener, which wasn't working. Therefore, I removed the maxLength attribute from xml, and began trying other things. Finally realized I made a mistake within my IF statement, and got that logic working, but continued trying to disable/enable the EditText programmatically with no luck. Turns out it really was as easy as setting the maxLength attribute. Confused myself by thinking about the extra steps that were needed in Xcode and thought it would be just as tedious in Android; boy was I wrong! Here is the solution I ended up with, along with the xml advice that user3347882 added above.

```
...
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            counterLabel.setText(characterMax - editable.toString().length() + " characters remaining");


            if (editText.length() == characterMax){

                counterLabel.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));


            }
            else{

                counterLabel.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

            }



        }
    });
```